# jQuery image carousel not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying create an image carousel whose speed relies upon mouse positioning (i.e. if the mouse is close to the edge of the screen it moves fast, directly in the middle it doesn't move etc.) **My issue right now being that the image carousel doesn't move at all.** Could be a variety of reasons for it not working, but I am not really sure as to why it isn't working or even if this is a 'good' carousel algorithm.

Created a speed function which I am positive needs work, but I will only be able to know that once I see the image carousel actually moving.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56rwR/)

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').mousemove(function(e) {
        var mpos = e.pageX;
        var speed = $(this).getSpeed(mpos);
        var dir = $(this).getDir(mpos);
        var $ul = $(this).children('ul');
        var cwidth = $ul.width();

        $('#speed').html(speed);

        if(speed != 0) {
            if(dir == -1){
                $ul.animate({
                    left: 0
                }, speed, 'linear');
            }
            if(dir == 1){
                $ul.animate({
                    left: -cwidth
                }, speed, 'linear');
            }
        }

    });
});

$.fn.getSpeed = function(mpos){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var center = width/2;
    var ps = (mpos-center)/10;
    var speed = ps * ps - (width % 100);

    if(speed >= 0) return speed;
    else return 0;
};

$.fn.getDir = function(mpos){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var center = width/2;

    if(mpos > center) return 1;
    else return -1;
};
```

### HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></li>
        .
        .
        .
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="speed"></div>
```

Comment: Lots of issues.  First, the ul width doesn't actually contain all of the li elements, it's just the width of the visible portion of the ul.  Second, the ul should be position absolute, so that you can legitimately use left positioning.  Third, it doesn't appear that your speed is as you intend - the farther away from the middle, the *slower* it will animate (the variable you've named *speed* is actually the total *time* it takes to make the animation.  Bigger numbers = takes longer).  Finally, the animate is being triggered repeatedly as you mouse over the carousel which is certainly a problem

Comment: @cale_b ok, so I have to invert the speed function. Next I see what you mean when you say the position needs to be absolute... so I can get the actual width... only thing is when I set the position to absolute the images disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems you have here.

First problem you got is, that position "relative" or "absolute" are missing on the ul.

```
carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

.carousel ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then you need to stop your animations before starting another:

```
$ul.stop().animate
```

But the biggest problem is, that your "speed" is not a real speed at all. 
If your speed is "100", it is very fast. This means that the animation will be done within 100 milliseconds! Thats so fast that you cannot see the animation.

So if you are moving your mouse near to the middle of you gallery it's moving fast and on the edges outside it's moving slow.

You could fix your speed by subtracting your actual mpos-value from a maximum-speed:

```
var speed = ps * ps - (width % 100);

// SPEED FIX
speed = 5000 - (speed * 2);
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/56rwR/1/

---

BUT!! this is buggy as hell because is has not a real speed.. only this animation time which is proportional to the ul-width..

I would recommend you to use a script like this here:
http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker

and write an hover event which increases/decreases the speed.

Comment: why would using a hover event as opposed to the mousemove event work better for speed?

Comment: So you did solve my issue, I just have to work out the kinks... but I am curious about the hover event for speed control

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your code to actually do what you want, but the main problem of not animating is fixed if you add the following css:

```
.carousel ul {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
```

always check the documentation if you run into trouble:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: position relative helps, but cale_b pointed out that in order to get the width of the entire ul position needs to be absolute